# Function of Subclass won't get called - SwiftUI

Tags: inheritance, swiftui, subclass, superclass

I am currently working with SwiftUI and need to implement a UIViewController class. From this specific class (ViewController), I would like that `Subclass` inherits from it.
My problem now is, when I am calling the function `setupAVCapture()` in the superclass, I thought that the override method in my subclass would get called first, and then the Method in the superclass when I call `super.setupAVCapture()`.
Am I missing something?

What I first did, was to implement a struct conforming to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` as follows:

```swift
struct AVCaptureView: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CameraViewController {
        let cameraVC = CameraViewController()
        return cameraVC
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraViewController, context: Context) { }
}
```

This class is getting called in my ContentView body.

Then the actual super class is implemented as follows:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
...
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAVCapture()
  }
  func setupAVCapture {
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Then the corresponding subclass looks something like this:

```swift
class Subclass: ViewController {
   override func setupAVCapture() {
        super.setupAVCapture()
        ...
   }
}
```

This method `override func setupAVCapture` should get called from its super class in the viewDidLoad Method. But what it does, it is calling the method in the superclass `func setupAVCapture()`

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible code for demo of your problem - those code are not testable and our replication might differ from your code.

Comment: A `superclass` doesn't call a method from a `Subclass` it goes the other way around. In theory the `ViewController` doesn't even know that the `Subclass` exists. You would have to tell it it is there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will edit the code above for more detailed code.

@loremipsum Ye I know but I thought if I override it in my subclass then it would get called but maybe I just misunderstood this one.

Comment: No, for example all people eat but some are vegetarian if your person would call the vegetarians eating method all people would be vegetarian.

Comment: Alright got it, so I guess I need to create an Instance of my Subclass to call the function